# Socat exec script in tunnel

Tags: tcp, exec, socat

I am running a tunnel like this:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:9090,fork TCP:192.168.1.3:9090
```

I would like to run a script to execute code with the strings passing through the tunnel.

The script does not change the strings, only processes strings independently but allows passage without changing between both ends.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked here. What kind of processing are you talking about? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

It's [possible now](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-exec.html) with socat v2.  socat v2 introduces the idea of [address chains](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-addresschain.html#dual).  You can run a script using `EXEC` where stdin/stdout(file descriptors 0 and 1) are connected to the listening socket and file descriptors 3 and 4 are connected to the sending socket:

```
socat - "TCP-LISTEN:localhost:8000 | EXEC:myscript.sh | TCP:myserver:80"
```

In the example myscript.sh:

- stdin(fd 0) - reads data from port 8000
- stdout(fd 1) - write data to port 8000
- fd 3 - reads data from myserver port 80
- fd 4 - writes data to myserver port 80