# socat forward input to both tcp-connect and exec (script)

Tags: networking, postfix, netcat, socat

I'm interested in implementing the [advanced content filter example](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#advanced_filter) for postfix.

`socat tcp-listen:10026,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:10025`

This is a simple "passthru" that works, but obviously doesn't do any filtering or responding.

My goal is to have this socat command work exactly as it does (two-way forwarding between the two connections), but also one-way forward its input to a PHP script.

**How would I do that?**

[Possible duplicate question (unanswered as of today)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312701/socat-exec-script-in-tunnel)

For more background... I would like to avoid the limitations of the "simple" content filter via [`pipe`](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) but I don't want to implement a full SMTP client and server to handle the `postfix <--> filter <--> postfix` transaction.

I do not need to filter the mail, but I do need to track it. My thought is that I could forward the network traffic per usual, but have a PHP script that tracks the data passing over the wire.

Comment: another way might be to use a milter in postfix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add `-v` to `socat` and it will copy all i/o to stderr, prefixed by `>` or `<` to indicate the direction.

Comment: I ended up using `xinetd` and PHP sockets, but this was very helpful in helping me move toward that solution. Thank you!